# Can't drop image from desktop with html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm newbie in html 5, and i'm trying some code for drop image from desktop, but my code doesn't work. This is my code:

```
script>
    function OnDropTextarea(event) {
        if (event.dataTransfer) {
            if (event.dataTransfer.files) {
                var leftbox = document.getElementById("leftbox");
                for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[i];
                    leftbox.innerHTML += file;
                }
            } else {
                alert("Your browser does not support the files property.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Your browser does not support the dataTransfer property.");
        }
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<section id="leftbox" ondrop="return OnDropTextarea (event);"></section>
```

So, please! help me

I try new code, but i can only drag and drop box in other box, not from desktop.
Another code:

```
<script>

    function doFirst() {
        mypic = document.getElementById('pic');
        mypic.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);

        leftbox = document.getElementById('leftbox');
        leftbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }, false);
        leftbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }, false);
        leftbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
    }

    function startDrag(e) {
        var code = '<img src="/assets/Koala.jpg">';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
    }

    function dropped(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        leftbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);

</script>
<section id="leftbox">
</section>
<section id="rightbox">
    <img src="/assets/Koala.jpg" id="pic"/>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `dragover` and `dragenter` and prevent the default action in order for an element to qualify as a valid drop target. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets)

**EDIT**: The drop should work now, I think (the only difference between your code in mine seems to be the fact that I also do `e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"` in my `dragover` and `dragenter` handlers). I wish people were more explicit with "doesn't work" - is the drop happening, but you're not getting the file contents?

If that is the case, the issue might be the fact that you are treating a `File` object as if it was a string. So instead of this,

```
leftbox.innerHTML += file;
```

try this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) { leftbox.innerHTML += e.target.result; };
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: I try new code have dragover and dragenter, but i can't drag and drop from desktop, please help me. I edited my question

Comment: It's doesn't work, but i find something on google with your code. Then i found a new code, it's the same with your code, and it work!!. Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ondrop="return OnDropTextarea (event);"
```

Should be:

```
ondrop="OnDropTextarea()"
```

Comment: Please see Amadan's answer as you need to override `dragover` and `dragenter` also.

Comment: I edited my question. Please! see is. I try code with dragover and dragenter, it work. But i can't drag and dop image from desktop :(

Answer (score 0):

May be this is useful for you,but you have to use the jquery library

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Upload images with Jquery</title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var obj = $("#dragandrophandler");
                obj.on('dragenter', function (e) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //$(this).css('border', '2px solid #0B85A1');
                });
                obj.on('dragover', function (e) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                obj.on('drop', function (e) 
                {   //alert('');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    /*$(this).css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');*/
                    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
                    var data = new FormData();
                    var i=0,l=files.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                         data.append('file' + i, files[i]);
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'load.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: false,
                        data: data,
                        processData: false,
                        cache: false
                    }).done(function(msg) {

                    });
                });

                $(document).on('dragenter', function (e) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $(document).on('dragover', function (e) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //obj.css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
                });
                $(document).on('drop', function (e) 
                {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #dragandrophandler {
                border: 2px dashed #ccc;
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dragandrophandler">
            Drop files here
        </div>
        <div id="meta"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it, but may be it doesn't work on ruby on rails

Comment: The source is client side(javascript) you have to proportionate your source from server side in the required language and replacing load.php by your script in ruby on rails